# how to make regular expression to match the string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am confusing about how to make any regular expressions.
e.g I have to make the regular expression of this type of string,

fetch/[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_São_Paulo_Zoo.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg)
fetch/[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_São_Paulo_Zoo.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg)

so I want to match only frm first string w_100 and from second string w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0 likewise different urls.

```
var regex = /[a-z]_[0-9a-z]/g;
var found = string.match(regex);
```

it shows me output something like,

> ["w_1","s_r","r_i","n_s"]

I want something like this

> ["w_100","h_100","fl_progressive","dpr_2.0",]

can anyone suggest me a regular expression for this.?

Comment: `[0-9a-z]` should be `[0-9a-z]+`. You need 1 or more. Ideally both should have one or more option: `/[a-z]+_[0-9a-z]+/g;`

Comment: should be `/[a-z]+_([a-z]+|[0-9]+\.(?=[0-9]+)/`

Comment: @Rajesh your answer gives me like this ["w_100", "hoenicopterus_ruber"] I don't want this.

Comment: @AZ_  Invalid regular expression: /[a-z]+_([a-z]+|[0-9]+\.(?=[0-9]+)/: Unterminated group

Comment: @Keval `/[a-z]+_([a-z]+|[0-9]+\.(?=[0-9]+))/` there was a typo.

Comment: @AZ_ can you please check but it's only giving me  ["fl_progressive",dpr_2.] for this rg/w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Zoo.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex

```js
let str = '/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0,ar_3:4,quality_auto:good,effect_auto_brightness,effect_auto_color:50,effect_green:-30/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_São_Paulo_Zoo.jpg'

console.log(str.match(/([a-z]+_([a-z]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(?=(,|\/)))/g))
```

> Update for added requirement.

```
console.log(str.match(/([a-z]+(?:_|:|:-)?([a-z]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(?=(,|\/)))+/g))
```

Comment: see "hoenicopterus_ruber" is also there. thanks for the answer. I'll sort it out.

Comment: what's the rule behind including `fl_progressive` but not `hoenicopterus_ruber`?

Comment: fl_progressive is the query parameter in the string URL. SO I want to extract it. btw thank you. now it's working fine.!

Comment: if i change the string to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/w_100,h_100,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0,ar_3:4,quality_auto:good,effect_auto_brightness,effect_auto_color:50,effect_green:-30/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_São_Paulo_Zoo.jpg now can you please change the regex according to the string?

Comment: updated regex is not working for upper example. can you please check and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have three characters matching for each match is because when you use the square brackets '`[]`', you are matching a single character from a possible range of characters. So your regex is currently looking for anything that has an alphabetic character between a-z, followed by an underscore, and finally another character between 0-9 or a-z.

To match multiple characters, you can add an asterisk '`+`' quantifier, which says the bit of regex that it is added to should match 1 or more times.

So to get the full matches, you can use the following: `/[a-z]+_[0-9a-z.]+/g`

However, this will also match `hoenicopterus_ruber` which is in the URLs.

To get around this issue, you can use a [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/11921403):

```
(?<=wikipedia\/|,)[a-z]+_[0-9a-z.]+
```

> **NOTE:** I've made the assumption that the URLs you are parsing are all wikipedia ones. If they are not, then you will need another solution for the second issue.

Comment: it's just a format for my request URL, it should be anything like name.jpg, but if in case image name like name_like_this.jpg then it should not be matched with regex.